# Arctan2 angle correction

Tags: numpy

I have a slight issue with determining the angles using arctan2 for two different set of data to obtain the same angle. I have a set of experimental data with angles and want to determine the angles for some angles matching those from the experimental data.

Example:

When I use

```
x = np.arange(-85,75,10) # same length of integers as z compared to
z = np.arange(85,245,10)
for y in range (5,175,10):
    a = np.arctan2(y,x/z) # angle in radians

b = np.rad2deg(a)
```

I understand that the angles in arctan2 (in radians) are determined in  counterclockwise approach but I want to get the same angle irrespective of how the data (x,z).

Reason been that if I use x at certain angle comparing the experimental data is different to using z, which is not what I want.

Comment: Please check that the edit respects the intent of the code. Also, can you specify what your analysis *should* do? What is the expected result?

Comment: @Pierre de Buyl thanks for the edit, I want to get the same angle for both cases of x and z. the first angle using x (176.6) and z (3.4). When I compare both angular results to my experimental data there is different values at both angles. I simply want a process were the results in both approach is the same, without any further modification

Comment: It is still not very clear what you want. What is `np.arctan2(y, x/z)` supposed to mean? `np.arctan2` returns angles in -π:π if your angles are close to π, you might be better off by redefining your measures. For instance, use -y instead of y and then add π (or 180° of course)

Comment: a = np.arctan2(y,x)
b = np.arctan2(y,z)

a and b above have different angles for each x and z. I have a set of coordinates that I want to input as x (-85,75,10) and z (85,225,10) I want to obtains a=b degrees so that either range of values can be used. I aim is to then use the variables as index into an array with magnitudes for each angle that I will get the same magnitude for both cases.  using -y instead of y only changes the angular sine from positive to negative I still have the same issue.